# Horizon/Ionic2 return a value

Tags: ionic2, rethinkdb, horizon

I want to return a value from Rethinkdb using Horizon:

```
ionViewLoaded() {
  let exampleValue;
  exampleValue = this.getValue();

  console.log(exampleValue); // gives me "undefined"
}

getValue() {
   let hz = new Horizon({host: "localhost:3100"});
   hz.connect();
   let table = hz('values');

   table.find(1).fetch().subscribe((val) => {
     return val;
   });
}
```

I need this value outside function and then I want to write simple if/else statement (if I do this into query then I get weird error - view is reloading over 200 times...). Is there anyway to return this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a service out of this whenever you are retrieving something from the database or an api. It's what it is made for.

Moving on with your question, the `exampleValue` is undefined in this case because `getValue` does not wait for the subscription to fire in `table.find(1).fetch()` thus returning an undefined.

What you can do is, return the observable and subscribe into it in your `ionViewLoaded` or make a `Promise` in `getValue`.

I'll just demonstrate option #1.

```
ionViewLoaded() {
  this.getValue().subscribe((exampleValue) => {
     console.log(exampleValue);
   });
}

getValue() {
   let hz = new Horizon({host: "localhost:3100"});
   hz.connect();
   let table = hz('values');

   return table.find(1).fetch();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. ;)